# Syncing to a feature service fails after join and field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, feature-service

I have access to a feature service, and I wish to make edits to it and then sync those edits.

Things I can do successfully:

Accessing the service:

- Add the feature service to my local ArcMap instance
- Create a local copy for editing

Editing:

- I can edit a single value by hand
- I can edit mutiple values by hand
- I can join another layer and use field calculator to update values

Syncing:

- I can sync a single edit done by hand
- I can sync multiple edits done by hand
- I **CANNOT** sync edits that were made using field calculator after a join

I get this error when trying to sync after edits were made using field calculator following a join:

[image]

Comment: That is strange. Check the server logs to see what errors (if any ) are in the logs. Be sure to log verbose/debug.

Comment: Have you tried removing the join before syncing?  It may be that the server doesn't like the way arc names the fields when joined (When joined, the fields are named like road_layer.TYPE; road_layer.NAME, join_layer.TYPE)

Comment: After a couple hours with ESRI on the phone I've found out it is a known error, not related to join/field calculator, but to the number of changes I was trying to sync.  I'll link to it when I find it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problems were caused not by field calculator, or join, but by a known bug in the sync workflow, where sync-large numbers of edits (I was told > 3000) automatically fail:

http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA4NDgyOA==

It is something they know about and are working on.

It only seemed like the join or field calculator were responsible because that was part of my workflow that involved > 3000 edits.